# firefox url bar has weird additional padding between the url text and globe/padlock icon

Tags: firefox

my firefox url bar has some weird padding on it. This doesn't happen on fresh install. This weird empty space just pop out of nowhere right after I customize my firefox a little bit wit add ons. So I tried to open it on safe mode, same thing happen. I tried to disable all add ons, problem persist.

[image: weird looking address bar]

[This](http://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/1n17yl/address_bar_padding_in_firefox_24/) is the only thread I found which has similar issue as mine, I tried to delete the prefs.js as suggested on that thread. The padding still there :(

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Start with a fresh install. Install add-ons one by one until the problem arises, then start over and don't use that add-on.

Comment: but if the problem really is on the add ins, shouldn't it got fixed when opening via safe mode?

Comment: Only one way to find out: please see my original comment.